# Drupal 6: stats for file downloads

Tags: drupal

Many of my sites offer MP3s available as download and playable via the [mp3 player](http://drupal.org/project/mp3player) module.  Now I need stats for how many times the MP3s are being accessed (played or downloaded).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Server: Hostgator VPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since handling stats in drupal is not really efficient, I think the best way to achieve this is to analyse you web server logs.

If you use apache, you will find free tools for this, like [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).
In addition, with this kind of tools, you can get a lot of useful stats.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is not the route I wanted to take, but is my last-ditch fallback.  Surely there must be a drupal way to do this?

Comment: No, not if you use public downloads. Drupal is not involved when a static file is accessed.

Comment: I sure wish there was a way for Drupal to GET involved!  Thanks.